# Setting cron job using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have a function that I want to execute through cron. If I simply hit the url `www.example.com/TestProjects/codeigniter/controller/function`

This function executes fine, if I set it on cron does not work.

I tried setting this as

```
public_html/TestProjects/codeigniter/controller/function
```

and this through such error message

```
public_html/TestProjects/codeigniter/controller/function: Not a directory
```

Can anyone help me how to set this on cron?

Comment: One option is to add `curl whatever > /dev/null` to your crontab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**   hi dude try this **
```

curl http://nztdemo.com/TestProjects/ERP/cron/index

Answer (score 2):

At first try to run that controller method in CLI mode.
In console, go to your project directory an then run your script in CLI mode:

```
    cd TestProjests/codeigniter
    php index.php controller function
```

If this will work, insert the same line to crontab, but with absolute path:

```
    php /path_to_your_projects/TestProjests/codeigniter/index.php controller function
```

This can also help you:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Comment: http://nztdemo.com/TestProjects/ERP/cron/index this is the actual path can u please create cron path for me

Comment: php /path_to_your_projects/TestProjests/ERP/index.php cron index (assuming that Codeigniter is installed in ERP dir, 'cron' is the name of your controller's class and index is a method in it)

Answer (score 1):

The path `public_html/TestProject/...` is almost certainly a relative path from your user directory. You can use `wget` in your cron to hit the url:

```
* * * * * wget http://www.example.com/cronscript > /dev/null
```

Alter the time above to let it run as much as you like

Comment: http://nztdemo.com/TestProjects/ERP/cron/index this is my actual path now please help

Comment: well, replace `http://www.example.com/...` for `http://nztdemo.com/...` ;) ofcourse I assume you know how to create or edit a crontab

Answer (score -1):

Use the system path to file name and function name after space to execute, it should look like this:

```
php /var/www/path/to/controller/classFile functionName
```